# Writing a dictionary to a csv file for another reuse

Tags: python-3.x, csv, dictionary

I have a dictionary:

```
inputdict = {key1: [value1,value2..], key2: [value1,value2..], key3: [value1,value2..]}
```

I want to write the data to a file dict.csv, in this style:

```
key1: [value11,value12,..]
key2: [value1,value22,..]
key3: [value31,value32,..]
```

I wrote:

```
import csv
with open(ouputfile, 'wb') as csv_file:
        writer = csv.writer(csv_file)
        for key, value in inputdict.items():
           writer.writerow([key: value])
```

But now I have an error:

```
 TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'
```

When I manage to write a file like this, I also want to read it back to a new dictionary.

the dictionary contains strings in keys and lists of integers. I want to reuse the dictionary by other scripts by reading from the csv file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write the file with `w` instead of `wb`. And when reading back in use `r` instead of `rb`.

Then you can do instead:

```
with open('/path/to/input_dict.csv','w') as fou:
    writer = csv.writer(fou)
    for k,v in inputdict.iteritems():
        writer.writerow(["{'%s':%s}" % (k,v)])
```

And to read it back in:

```
import ast
with open('/path/to/input_dict.csv','r') as fin:
    for line in fin:
        ast.literal_eval(ast.literal_eval(line))
```

However you should be able to do what you want easier with [`pickle`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/pickle.html):

```
import pickle
with open('/path/to/input.csv', 'wb') as fou:
    pickle.dump(inputdict,fou)
```

And to read:

```
with open('/path/to/input.csv', 'rb') as fin:
    inputdict = pickle.load(fin)
```

Comment: thanks for the response, I tried the first option because I have to give the results in a readable file like csv to be used by other programs. Is it possible for pickles too?

Comment: You're very welcome. No, that's not possible with pickles.